# Get Windows "Scale and Layout" using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, scale

Is there a way to get the Windows "**Scale and Layout**" using CSS?

[image]

Comment: You could [detect the pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541676/what-are-best-practices-for-detecting-pixel-ratio-density) in Javascript and act upon that. But you won't find any CSS-only solutions.

Comment: @Zenoo is there any way to change this % using JavaScript?

Comment: No, this is a user setting. You don't have access to it.

Comment: @Zenoo 
Ok.. Thank You.