# How do I use media queries without ruining zooming on desktops?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to use media queries to make my website responsive to changes in the window size. This is basic good practice and allows for people on any device to use my website.

Currently, I am doing this with lines similar to the following:

```
@media (min-width: 30rem) and (max-width: 40rem) {
```

The problem is that doing this ruins zooming. As you zoom in, you move through media queries. This is ridiculous. The entire point of the zoom is to see a blown up region of the fullsize page, not to change the page.

Thus, the question is as follows: How do I make media queries respond to changes in the window size but not to changes in the zoom level?

Comment: Are you able to add an example to your question?

Comment: what i use in my media queries is the next line:
@media only screen and (max-width:200px){}
that doesnt affect the zoom on my pages try it, I hope it could help you

Comment: Edy, I tried your suggestion and the zoom still changes the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar problem, and this is the solution that worked for me so far. In this example, I want to hide the red box only if we are on mobile, not in zoomed desktop.

Based on: [Andrii Verbytskyi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770411/1541113). *In his solution he used matchQuery to handle zoom with Javascript, I've just translated his work to CSS and it seems to work nice.

Let's say we have our simple media query rule defined like: **less or equal than 768px width is mobile** and **everything else is desktop** and we have our element "zoom-test" defined like this:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom-test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="zoom-test"></div>
    <style>
        .zoom-test{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color:red;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
            .zoom-test{
                display: none;
            }
        }
        @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 10/9), (min-resolution: 1.1dppx),(min-width: 769px){
            .zoom-test {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Queries for catching zoom greather than 1 in most browsers:

1. -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1
2. min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1
3. -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 10/9
4. min-resolution: 1.1dppx

For catching the viewport width:

1. min-width: 769px (desktop query for the example)

**Tested on Chrome, Safari and Firefox**

Read [this article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3811-looking-at-how-browser-zoom-affects-css-media-queries-and-pixel-density.htm) too, it's crystal clear.

Hope that helps!