# Problem showing real sizes on Apple device's screens (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, devicepixelratio

I need to show real sizes of objects on screen (1mm - 20mm). At the top, I have a button "Calibrate view". I click it and a modal opens where user can calibrate view using a credit card (Put it on screen, and using + and - buttons, he adjusts the slider until the lines matches credit's height). User submit calibration. After this, for every element I run a function:

Credit card width is 85.6mm;
card__pad - is the container that has at the bottom and on top lines, that user need to match with credit's height;

```
function mmToPx(mm) {
    return parseFloat($('.card__pad').width()) * mm / 85.6
} 
// 20 mm show
$('.obj').css('width', mmToPx(20))
```

This code works perfectly on Desktop and Android (at least tested with my phone), but on Apple device, object doesn't look 20mm, but a little smaller. Tell me please what is wrong here, what need to be used for showing correct size on Apple devices??

[image]

Comment: I assume this will only work when you also do the calibration on an iOS device. The pixels-per-inch can be different depending on each particular device.

Comment: Yes, user first put his credit card on screen to calibrate view. Once card's container matches, he press calibrate and all objects will be resized. I think it is somehow connected with window.devicepixelratio, but I dont have an apple device to live test results

Comment: Just out of interest, did you try to use `mm` units in CSS directly? Because this should use the correct pixel-to-device ratio automatically.

Comment: Yes, works only on desktop. On android and Apple devices looks like 40%-75% of real mm. This method with card works on desktop and android, but I dont know why it doesnt work on Apple.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for setting up the height reading? What function are you using to find the position of the lines?

Answer (score 0):

A thing to keep in mind is that all iOS devices use a [HiDPI screen](https://blog.elementary.io/what-is-hidpi/) which they call a "Retina display", meaning that there are more physical pixels there in the same space as on a standard screen.

That also means that `1px` is not actually `1px` because now there is the concept of pixels vs. display pixels.  Because the physical pixels are so small on HiDPI making something with a `border: 1px solid red` would be too small and not what the developer intended, that 1px size actually displays on multiple physical pixels to achieve the same look. Some Android devices also use a higher pixel density, but maybe the ones you tested on didn't use that?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541676/what-are-best-practices-for-detecting-pixel-ratio-density) might be worth looking into, but first make sure that you are using this meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`

You can use `window.devicePixelRatio` to get... well the device pixel ratio.  You may want to plug this in to your function and see what it returns on various devices. I'm currently on a Windows machine with a 24" Dell monitor and it returns `0.8999999761581421` for me.

I know this isn't a total answer for your code since I can't really test on multiple devices right now, but I hope this can point you in the right direction.