# HTML5 msBackingStorePixelRatio and window.devicePixelRatio don't exist - are there workarounds for high definition canvas?

Tags: html, windows-phone, html5-canvas

Working with a javascript-based hybrid mobile app, I had problems with blurry text being drawn in a canvas. I found suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661339/how-do-i-fix-blurry-text-in-my-html5-canvas/15666143#15666143), which fixed things on Android and iOs. But not in Windows phone (our app uses IE10).

Adding a debug div and this code to the app:

```
var PIXEL_RATIO = (function () {
    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
        dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        bsr = ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
              ctx.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
    return dpr / bsr;
}());
$('#debugg').append(" PR=" + PIXEL_RATIO);
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
$('#debugg').append(" msr=" + ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio);
```

Outputs "PR=1 msr=undefined", which indicates that the msBackingStorePixelRatio property is not defined on canvas contexts in IE10. I had a look in IE10 on a desktop PC, and using the developer tools I can't seem to find it there either - the same applies to window.devicePixelRatio.

What to do? I tried changing the default for dpr to 2 above, which makes it look nice on Windows Phone, and it works on an Android phone and an iPhone here. But can I depend on window.devicePixelRatio aways being set for non-MS platforms, or 2 being a generally appropriate value? Is there some other way to find a ratio to use when rescaling to high definition canvas drawing?

Comment: Your question has a duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383503/window-devicepixelratio-does-not-work-in-ie-10-mobile), with a good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20204180/1396177).